# Confusing with passing multi-word arguments

Tags: bash, scripting, arguments

I'm missing some basic idea about bash, and I don't know what to google!

I'm trying to do the following:

File `future.sh`:

```bsh
START_DATE="$1"

NEXT=`date "$START_DATE +3 days"`
echo $NEXT
```

Then

```
> ./future.sh "Sep 3 9am"
date: invalid date ‘Sep 3 9am +3 days’
```

Yet,

```
> date -d "Sep 3 9am +3 days"
Fri Sep  6 09:00:00 CEST 2019
```

---

Obviously, something goes wrong with argument passing / string building. But I don't get it!

I also tried shifting around quotes, single quotes (`'`), and using `$(...)` instead of backticks.

Comment: Yes, there is an issue with the arguments. You omit the `-d` in one of the calls to `date`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

looks like in your script the option `-d` is missing.
Try:

```
NEXT=`date -d "$START_DATE +3 days"`
```

Comment: oh man, how did I miss this.